# Which query would be faster, a table with 4 million rows 3 cols or 20K rows with 200 col?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I think it can be very lame question but I am bit confused & I am not a DB expert. Let me come to the question:

Say, I have two tables A & B.

Table A has 4 columns but 4 Million rows.
ID(P), Key_id(Foreign Key), Value

Table B has 200 columns but 20K rows.
ID(P), Field 1,....N

Now, my question is which one will be faster:

1. If I fire a select query on table A to fetch set of records, based on Key_id values & we need to do one join as well with another table say C to get the value of Key_id

Output:

Key_Value| Key_ID| Value

2. If I fire a select query to fetch a record with all 200 columns?

Output:

ID| all 200 columns...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would need to test on your data and your system.  Providing two inconsistent database tags does help your question either.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : Regarding two diff database, right now we are using MySQL but we are planning to go for Postgres. That's why I tagged two.

Comment: If you are thinking of splitting up a table so that each row ends up as a couple of key/value pairs, don't do it. It i a bad idea. If you have lots and lots of rare columns, consider `jsonb` for the rare and unimportant ones.

Comment: It sounds like you're contemplating [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model). There are some *limited* situations where it can make sense but the usual instinct should be to avoid it. It limits your ability to use SQL tools effectively (such as indexes)